# FastAPI Post Request with a Username and role, how to do it?

Tags: python, post, grafana, fastapi

I want to make a FastAPI Post Request to an instance, with this Post Request I want to add a user to a Grafana Organisation. For that, I have to send a post request with the Attributes `loginOrEmail` and `Role`. But how do I send such a Post Request?

This is the current state of my code.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

class User(BaseModel):
    loginOrEmail: "user"
    role: "Viewer"

app = FastAPI()

app.post("myGrafanaOrganisation http Link")
async def add_user(user: User):
    return user
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what the `app.post` decorator is supposed to do; FastAPI is a http api server - not an http client. The argument given to `@app.post` (the `@` is  important) is the path of the _incoming request_. For outgoing requests you can use the `requests` or `aiohttp` libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood what the app.post decorator is supposed to do; FastAPI is a http api server - not an http client. The argument given to @app.post (the @ is important) is the path of the incoming request. For outgoing requests you can use the requests or aiohttp libraries.